# Autohide Rows Based on DV Dropdown Menu - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas about this, I feel like something is going over my head as I believe this should work...

I have a data validation dropdown menu on cell A11 containing (Select Property, Hotel, Hostel, Cabin)

I've defined the names of Rows 22:52 as 'RLHotel', rows 53:85 as 'RLHostel' and rows 86:115 as 'RLCabin'. Essentially I'm trying to give the user the option to pick out what type of property they're trying to fill out a rooming list for.

If they select 'Hotel' on the drop down menu, I want Hostel/Cabin to hide. If they 'Hostel', I want Hotel/Cabin to hide, etc.

The code I'm using in VBA for the this specific Worksheet is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A11")) Is Nothing Then
    With Range("$A$11")
        Range("RLHotel, RLCabin").EntireRow.Hidden = .Value = "Hostel"
        Range("RLHostel, RLCabin").EntireRow.Hidden = .Value = "Hotel"
        Range("RLHostel, RLHotel").EntireRow.Hidden = .Value = "Cabin"
    End With
End If


End Sub
```

Currently, If I select 'Hotel', only the 'Cabin' rows hide. If I select 'Hostel', all rows are showing. If I select 'Cabin', the Hostel and Hotel rows hide as they should.

Anyone have any ideas? Would be greatly appreciated, been searching on this forever! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead, I think you were overthinking it by trying to operate on two non-contiguous ranges (e.g., `Range("RLHotel", "RLHostel")`.  Just flip the operator in the boolean expression to `<>` and set the `Hidden` property for each type of property thusly:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A11")) Is Nothing Then
    With Range("$A$11")
        Range("RLHotel").EntireRow.Hidden = .Value <> "Hotel"
        Range("RLHostel").EntireRow.Hidden = .Value <> "Hostel"
        Range("RLCabin").EntireRow.Hidden = .Value <> "Cabin"
    End With
End If


End Sub
```

If A11 is linked (by formula) to a cell on another worksheet, then instead of using the `_Change` event use the `_Calculate` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    With Range("$A$11")
        Range("RLHotel").EntireRow.Hidden = .Value <> "Hotel"
        Range("RLHostel").EntireRow.Hidden = .Value <> "Hostel"
        Range("RLCabin").EntireRow.Hidden = .Value <> "Cabin"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Was about to post the same solution.

Comment: Ahhhh thank you haha, I can't believe I've been staring at that for so long and didn't see.

Comment: Quick question, not sure if this is an easy fix. Using your fixed script above, Cell A11 is now not a DV Drop Down Menu, but is linked to a DV dropdown menu on a different worksheet. When I change the selection on the drop down menu that A11 points to, it doesn't auto hide/show the ranges (RLHotel,RlHostel,RLCabin). I've tried adding Application.Volatile but that didn't fix. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use the Change event in the *other* sheet, then,  to control this because a formula evaluation -- even if the value changes -- doesn't trigger the Change event

Comment: Hmm I see what you're saying, but the property (Cabin,Hostel,Hotel) needs to be next to each property in a separate tab where hundreds of properties are listed. So for instance when I enter a new property 'Best Western Stackoverflow' as a hotel, whenever the sheet calls upon BW Stackoverflow then it will change to a hotel type property. I don't really see a way of putting the Change event on the property tab where the DV dropdown menu is changing, because I don't need to change anything there.

Comment: Hmm. Try using the `Calculate` event. See revision to my answer, above.

Comment: Got it! I used the code I commented below in the Workbook code

Answer (score 0):

This is in reference to the comments on the answer. This was the final solve to make it update on each tab so I can build out more and it will automatically populate.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal   Target As   Range)
Application.Volatile


With Sheet4.Range("$A$11")
    Sheet4.Range("RLHotel").EntireRow.Hidden = .Value <> "Hotel"
    Sheet4.Range("RLHostel").EntireRow.Hidden = .Value <> "Hostel"
    Sheet4.Range("RLCabin").EntireRow.Hidden = .Value <> "Cabin"
End With

With Sheet12.Range("$A$11")
    Sheet12.Range("RLHotel").EntireRow.Hidden = .Value <> "Hotel"
    Sheet12.Range("RLHostel").EntireRow.Hidden = .Value <> "Hostel"
    Sheet12.Range("RLCabin").EntireRow.Hidden = .Value <> "Cabin"
End With

End Sub
```